# Run macro at specific time when check box is checked(manual calculation)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro in excel at a specific time if check box is checked.
It is working as it should, only problem is that it works only when
workbook is set to automatic calculations and I need workbook to be set to manual calculations.

Here is a VBA code I'm using in that file:
sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim time_dt As Date
time_dt = Cells(1, 7)

If Range("C1").Value = "YES" Then
Application.OnTime TimeValue(time_dt), "FillFirstColumn"
End If

End Sub
```

and here is a Module 1 code:

```
Sub FillFirstColumn()
Range("A1:A20").Value = "YES"
End Sub
```

When I click on check box, cell D1 is changing from FALSE to TRUE. In a cell C1 I have this formula =IF(D1=TRUE,"YES","NO"). And C1 is not recalculating unless a workbook is set to automatic.

Based on advice from a comment below I've added this VBA code to sheet1:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "C").Calculate
End Sub
```

but formula in C1 is still not recalculating.

Comment: You might try a publicly shared link to a reputable file share (Google drive, Dropbox, etc) that allows redistribution of macro-enabled workbooks but people are generally reluctant (and rightfully so) to open macro enabled workbooks downloaded from the interweb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Calculate all open workbooks, one workbook with many worksheets, one worksheet, a range of cells in a worksheet or a single cell.

```
thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet1").cells(2, "B").calculate
```

The above will recalculate a single cell (Sheet1!B2) in the workbook that the sub procedure was running in.

Comment: Basically the problem is that when i click on check box I need to recalculate a specific cell in order to run a macro at specific time.It workd while the workbook is set to automatic calculations but it is not working when it is set to manual calculations

Comment: Yes, I understood that. My response was intended to suggest that whatever needs to be recalculated can be recalculated without xlCalculationAutomatic directly through the sub procedure that is run on the timer.

Comment: I know about recalculation command you mentioned above, the problem is that I don't know how to activate recalculation of a cell when I click on a check box.

Comment: Perhaps within `Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()` ?

Comment: I've tried it but for some reason it doesn't work. When I click on check box, cell D1 is changing from FALSE to TRUE. In a cell C1 I have this formula =IF(D1=TRUE,"YES","NO"). And C1 is not recalculating unless a workbook is set to automatic.

Comment: Can you edit your original question above to include your code and a brief narrative explaining the new situation?

Comment: OK. Problem solved. I had to assign CheckBox1_Click() macro to a check box.Thank you for your help.